# Import a C console program for an ios swift project

Tags: ios, c, swift, xcode, import

I am just getting started with swift and I would like to import some projects I did in C.
To stay simple let's say I want to import a console program written in C.
I saw how to import .c and .h files but is there a way I can have a virtual console showing on the ios device with a keyboard so I can interact with the app?

Comment: Not really. iOS is not terminal based.

Comment: That's why; I'm looking for something that looks like a terminal, but it can be anything as long as it works!

Comment: You would have to create your own input and output using a UItextView and a UITextField, but stdin and stdout are directed to /dev/null so you would also need to modify your code to take that into account. You can use Swift to write  Mac OS app. Mac OS is unix-based so it does have a standard command line environment